# DataTables/jQuery UI Tabs header width bug

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datatables, jquery-ui-tabs

So there is a well known bug with DataTables + jQuery UI Tabs where the column headers cannot be calculated properly due to the DataTable being initially hidden, this prevents the sort icon from being shown as the width is off the screen - http://datatables.net/examples/api/tabs_and_scrolling.html.

In the link above it says to fix this inside the tabs `onActivated` method like so:

```
   $("#tabs").tabs({
        active: obj["currentTabIndex"],
        activate: function(event, ui) {
            $("#example").DataTable().columns.adjust();
            chrome.storage.local.set({"currentTabIdx": ui.newPanel[0].dataset["tabIndex"]});
        }
    });
```

However, as you can see I am saving the tab that was selected so that when the user reloads the page, the same tab that they left on was open.

On reload, the tab that was selected shows however the `activate` event does not fire as the tab wasn't selected, merely loaded.

I have tried adjusting the columns inside the `activate`, `load`, `create` methods etc but nothing works.

Is there a solution for this?

Comment: Have you tried to trigger a click event on the loaded tab?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3804523/activating-second-tab-in-page-load-using-jquery

Comment: In jquery tabs documentation, you will find that the first tab set to show up does not fire the activate event.  You need to trigger it some other way or used the document ready event handler to set it up.

Answer (score 0):

I create 3 tabs each with their own datatable.  I used scrolling as shown in the link to Datatables.net.
see it here 
http://jsbin.com/vawonud/edit?output

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        // this section sets up the data and creates the columns defintion
        // based on the data
        dtdata = JSON.parse(f);
        var keys = Object.keys(dtdata.data[0]);
        var columns = [];
        $.each(keys, function (i, item) {
            columns.push({ data: item, title: item, name: item })
        });

        // Get the storage  value if it is there then create tabs
        var ls = localStorage.getItem("currentTabIdx");
        if (ls === null) { ls = 1; localStorage.setItem("currentTabIdx", idx); };
        $("#tabs").tabs(
            {
                active: ls - 1,
                activate: function (evt, ui) {
                    var idx = ui.newPanel.index();
                    localStorage.setItem("currentTabIdx", idx);
                    if (!$.fn.DataTable.isDataTable("#table" + idx)) {
                        $("#table" + idx).DataTable({
                            data: dtdata.data, columns: columns, order: [[idx, "asc"]], scrollY: 200,
                            scrollCollapse: true,
                            paging: false
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
            );
        // initialize the exposed table
        $("#table" + localStorage.getItem("currentTabIdx")).DataTable({
            data: dtdata.data, columns: columns, order: [[ls, "asc"]], scrollY: 200,
            scrollCollapse: true,
            paging: false
        });
    });
```